# Assigning a class to an element once it's appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, setattribute

So I currently have slider that the user can dynamically fill upon uploading images. I'm using bootstrap for the slider which requires the first slide to have the class "active" in order to work, however when I try to assign that class to the first slide using

```
"if ($("#carousel-inner").find('li')) {

          var slide1 = document.getElementById("slide-0");

              slide1.setAttribute ("class", "active");

            }
```

it doesn't recognize the slide id and assigns null to the value, returning "cannot setAttribute of null".

Any advice?

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow-container">
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-inner" id ="carousel-inner">
 
</ul>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
$('#_uploadImages').click(function () {
    $('#_imagesInput').click();

    setTimeout(activeness(), 5000)
});

$('#_imagesInput').on('change', function () {
    handleFileSelect();
});
}


function handleFileSelect() {
    //Check File API support
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {

        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        var output = document.getElementById("carousel-inner");
        var arrFilesCount = [];
        var start = $(output).find('li').length;
        var end = start+ files.length;
        var nonImgCount = 0;
        var slide1 = document.getElementById("slide1")
        var display =  document.getElementById("displayImg")
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            arrFilesCount.push(i); // push to array
        }
        
        if(start !== 0){
            $(output).find('li > nav > a.prev').first().attr('href','#slide-' + (end-1));
            $(output).find('li > nav > a.next').last().attr('href','#slide-'+start);

            
        }


        
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            var file = files[i];

            //Only pics
            if (!file.type.match('image')) {nonImgCount++; continue;}

            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var picFile = event.target;

                current_i = arrFilesCount.shift();
                if (current_i === 0) {
                    prev_i = files.length - 1; //This is for the first element. The previous slide will be the last image. (i=length-1)
                } else {
                    prev_i = current_i - 1;
                }
                if (arrFilesCount.length - nonImgCount === 0) {
                    next_i = 0;
                } else {
                    next_i = current_i + 1; //This is for the last element. The next slide will be the first image (i=0)
                }
                

                display.src = picFile.result

                output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + '<li id="slide-' + current_i + '" class="carousel-item">' + "<img class='d-block w-100' src='" + picFile.result + "'" + "title=''/>" + '</li>'; // TODO: Enter Title
                
             
                
                
            });
            //Read the image
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            


           
        }
     
       

        if ($("#carousel-inner").find('li')) {
         
          var slide1 = document.getElementById("slide-0");

              slide1.setAttribute ("class", "active");
          
            }
    } else {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, try like this  : `$("#carousel-inner").find('li:eq(0)').addClass("active")` see if that works .